# Speed issue with image classification on mobile video, could tf.browser.fromPixels be solution?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm testing image classification on Safari 13 IOS with video HTML element and Tensorflow.js with Mobilenet. I get predictions but unlike on my laptop, it is really slow (predictions coming every few seconds with video freezing).

```
  console.log('Loading mobilenet..');

  // Load the model.
  net = await mobilenet.load();
  console.log('Successfully loaded model');

  // Create an object from Tensorflow.js data API which could capture image
  // from the web camera as Tensor.
  const webcam = await tf.data.webcam(video);
  while (true) {
    const img = await webcam.capture();
    const result = await net.classify(img);

    document.getElementById('console').innerText = `
      prediction: ${result[0].className}\n
      probability: ${result[0].probability}
    `;
    // Dispose the tensor to release the memory.
    img.dispose();

    // Give some breathing room by waiting for the next animation frame to
    // fire.
    await tf.nextFrame();
  }
}

app();
```

I guess the problem is that capturing and predicting all the time is too much for the app to handle. So, when I came cross this code snippet from developers of Emoji Scavenger Hunt, I became interested:

```
  if (this.isRunning) {
    const result = tfc.tidy(() => {

      const pixels = tfc.fromPixels(camera.videoElement);
      const centerHeight = pixels.shape[0] / 2;
      const beginHeight = centerHeight - (VIDEO_PIXELS / 2);
      const centerWidth = pixels.shape[1] / 2;
      const beginWidth = centerWidth - (VIDEO_PIXELS / 2);
      const pixelsCropped =
            pixels.slice([beginHeight, beginWidth, 0],
                         [VIDEO_PIXELS, VIDEO_PIXELS, 3]);

      return this.emojiScavengerMobileNet.predict(pixelsCropped);
    });

    const topK =
        await this.emojiScavengerMobileNet.getTopKClasses(result, 10);

    this.checkEmojiMatch(topK[0].label, topK[1].label);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(() => this.predict());
}
```

This slicing technique is not familiar to me. I have tried to copy their Typescript code to JS without working results so far. Could someone point me to right direction?

So what I want is to capture a 224x224 image of my video stream to my net.classify prediction function every X milliseconds. I guess tf.browser.fromPixels will be helpful here? Thank you so much!

Comment: Not a solution but just a tip: Have a look at [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) they van move part of the code to a seperate thread so it will not freeze as often / anymore. Also `while (true)` is probably not the best solution for an ongoing loop.

Comment: "Give some breathing room by waiting for the next animation frame to fire" there is no breathing room whatsoever. A Promise means "finish what you're doing and then call me immediately". That's why they use `requestAnimationFrame(() => this.predict());` This won't speed up your code, but it will reduce the load.

Comment: Haha I see, "breathing room" comes from this tutorial I have followed https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-teachablemachine-codelab/index.html#5 . I'll take a look into requestAnimationFrame(()! Comes without saying but I'm new to Javascript. Thanks to you both! If someone has used tf.browser.fromPixels  with video stream I'd love to hear.

Comment: Have a look at the tf.js demos such as PoseNet, Blazeface, etc. They get very good performance on a mobile browser.